# Capturing responses from Jenkins with jq

Tags: jquery, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, try-catch, devops

I'm currently working on a jenkinsfile that does not have any method of catching responses whether the job done was success or not.

Currently it looks like this

```
      steps {
        sh """
        #!/bin/bash
        curl -d '{ \"ref\": \"${env.BRANCH_NAME}\" }' \\
          -H \"Accept: application/json\" \\
          '#somelink/api' \\
          -k -q
        """
      }
    }
  }
  post {
    success {
      slackSend(
        color: 'good',
        message: "Build success : ${env.JOB_NAME}-${env.BUILD_NUMBER}. <${env.BUILD_URL}|Go to build>"
      )
    }
    failure {
      slackSend(
        color: 'danger',
        message: "Build failed : ${env.JOB_NAME}-${env.BUILD_NUMBER}. <${env.BUILD_URL}|Go to build>"
      )
    }
    aborted {
      slackSend(
        color: '#858384',
        message: "Build aborted : ${env.JOB_NAME}-${env.BUILD_NUMBER}. <${env.BUILD_URL}|Go to build>"
      )
    }
```

and in Jenkins it would show a result of

````
```+ curl -d '{ "ref": "service" }' -H 'Accept: application/json' http://somelink/payload -k -q

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current

                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed


  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100    20    0     0  100    20      0     19  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--    19
100    20    0     0  100    20      0      9  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--     9
100    20    0     0  100    20      0      6  0:00:03  0:00:03 --:--:--     6
100    20    0     0  100    20      0      4  0:00:05  0:00:04  0:00:01     4
100    20    0     0  100    20      0      3  0:00:06  0:00:05  0:00:01     3
100    20    0     0  100    20      0      3  0:00:06  0:00:06 --:--:--     0
100    20    0     0  100    20      0      2  0:00:10  0:00:07  0:00:03     0
100    20    0     0  100    20      0      2  0:00:10  0:00:08  0:00:02     0
100    20    0     0  100    20      0      2  0:00:10  0:00:09  0:00:01     0
100    20    0     0  100    20      0      1  0:00:20  0:00:10  0:00:10     0
100    20    0     0  100    20      0      1  0:00:20  0:00:11  0:00:09     0
100    20    0     0  100    20      0      1  0:00:20  0:00:12  0:00:08     0
100    20    0     0  100    20      0      1  0:00:20  0:00:13  0:00:07     0
100    20    0     0  100    20      0      1  0:00:20  0:00:14  0:00:06     0
100    20    0     0  100    20      0      1  0:00:20  0:00:15  0:00:05     0
100    20    0     0  100    20      0      1  0:00:20  0:00:16  0:00:04     0
100    20    0     0  100    20      0      1  0:00:20  0:00:17  0:00:03     0
100    20    0     0  100    20      0      1  0:00:20  0:00:18  0:00:02     0
100    20    0     0  100    20      0      1  0:00:20  0:00:19  0:00:01     0
100    20    0     0    0    20      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:20 --:--:--     0
100    20    0     0    0    20      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:21 --:--:--     0
100    20    0     0    0    20      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:22 --:--:--     0
100    20    0     0    0    20      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:23 --:--:--     0
100    20    0     0    0    20      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:24 --:--:--     0
100    20    0     0    0    20      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:25 --:--:--     0
100    20    0     0    0    20      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:26 --:--:--     0
100    20    0     0    0    20      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:27 --:--:--     0
100    20    0     0    0    20      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:28 --:--:--     0
100    20    0     0    0    20      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:29 --:--:--     0
100    20    0     0    0    20      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:30 --:--:--     0
100    20    0     0    0    20      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:31 --:--:--     0
100    20    0     0    0    20      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:32 --:--:--     0
100    20    0     0    0    20      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:33 --:--:--     0
100    20    0     0    0    20      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:34 --:--:--     0
100    20    0     0    0    20      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:35 --:--:--     0
100    20    0     0    0    20      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:36 --:--:--     0
100    20    0     0    0    20      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:37 --:--:--     0
100    20    0     0    0    20      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:38 --:--:--     0
  0  4847    0     0    0    20      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:39 --:--:--     0{"status":"success","message":"triggered: umask 0022; r10k deploy environment service -pv\n\nWARN\t -> Environment \"SOMEBRANCH\"```
````

What I'm trying to achieve here is to capture the `"status":"success"` and if that shows up then it should proceed to the `success {}` step. Else it goes into the `failure{}` step.

The script runs fine, and produces the result that it should, however there are certain cases where `"status":` doesn't always show up as success but it still shows on jenkins that it's all good. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: From what I can understand, please look into this: https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2016/07/18/pipeline-notifications/ This gives you a lot of control over what you want to do on success and failure.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to capture the output you should do so:

```
      steps {
        def captured_output = sh returnStdout: true, script: """
        #!/bin/bash
        curl -d '{ \"ref\": \"${env.BRANCH_NAME}\" }' \\ ...
```

While there, you might want to suppress `curl` debug output with `-s` or `--silent` option:

```
curl -s -d ...
```

You can then parse the output, provided it's a valid JSON:

```
def parsed_data = readJSON text: captured_output
```

If the response in `status` field is not success, you can fail the build:

```
    if (parsed_data.status != "success") {
        error ("Miserably failed")
    }
```

Your post step will then get into `failure` clause.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok to install [http request plugins](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/http_request/) it would really help you to achieve your expectation and it's quite simple to parse the response

```
pipeline {
    agent any;
    stages {
        stage('call api') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def response = httpRequest url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/json?pretty=true', authentication: 'credentialsID', customHeaders:[[name:'Accept', value:"application/json"]]
                    println("Status: "+response.status)
                    println("Content: "+response.content)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```